# implementing dark theme in my app; different color is showing in toolbar of different activity

Tags: android, styles, android-dark-theme

I wanted to implement dark theme in my app; it has a toolbar in mainactivity and action bar in other activity. I implemented dark theme in values/styles.xml as below:

```xml
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary_material_dark</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark_material_dark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/material_deep_teal_200</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
</resources>
```

After doing this, my app became in dark theme but the color of toolbar of main activity is diiferent and color of action bar of other activity are different. And, there is also a kind of blink while going to another activity.

In my main activity there are cardview made by recyclerview; I wanted to implement dark theme as of this picture.
[image: Dark Theme]

I don't know why the color of toolbar is changing while going from main activity to other activity(other activity have actionbar) and the background is blinking while going from one activity to another.

I also want to set the color of entire background of layout color of cardview as given picture. 
I tried to do this so many time but it is not happening the background is blinking :(

By the way, this is my toolbar's xml(app_bar_main.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    ..
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
             />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton.../>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: *The toolbar of main activity is of different color and actionbar of other activity*. Post your Toolbar layout. Which color are you using?

Comment: oh, in toolbar there was background of primarycolor; thank you @GabrieleMariotti sir. please also suggest me how can i change background colour of layout and background color of cardview of that layout?

Comment: The default backgroundColor used by the cardView is `?attr/colorSurface`.

Comment: and how can i change the background color of layout; the default given by Theme.MaterialComponents is not good

Comment: What do you mean with color of layout? A lot of components have an own background color. Try to set the android:colorBackground

Comment: toolbar's problem is not solved even after removing its background and theme attribute? @GabrieleMariotti help me please

Comment: To help you have to post the layout and the styles used.

Comment: shall i link you the project @GabrieleMariotti sir? it is also blinking when going form one activity to another and toolbar color are different in different activity(i mean in main activity there is toolbar and in other activity there is action bar and color are different in them) please sir please

Comment: Just post here the layout with the toolbar, the app theme and the styles involved with AppBar/Toolbar.

Comment: sir i've updated my question and this is the link please help me @GabrieleMariotti sir. it took my so many days. please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/MyAppBar"
        ..>
```

where:

```
<style name="MyAppBar" parent="@style/Widget.Design.AppBarLayout">
    <item name="android:background">?attr/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:elevation">xxdp</item>
    ...
</style>
```

Comment: this is the [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1VGZrPMkhXXswcNaD0bX8GxkPiiv5opRJ) please help me @GabrieleMariotti sir

Comment: i did as you suggested still it is changing color and blinking when going to another activity @GabrieleMariotti sir

Comment: Why would you need to set the elevation of the appbar?